# Netbeans JPopupMenu Issues

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jpopupmenu

I made a popup menu in Netbeans and I want to make a menu item that sends me to another GUI when I press it, but I don't know how.

I have to do something like a restaurant menu and when someone presses the button from the menu to send them to a specific type of food.

I made it only to popup when I right click it.

```
private void formMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
  if(evt.isPopupTrigger()){
      jPopupMenu1.show(evt.getComponent(),evt.getX(),evt.getY());
  }
}                                 

private void formMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    if(evt.isPopupTrigger()){
      jPopupMenu1.show(evt.getComponent(),evt.getX(),evt.getY());
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I want to make a menu item that sends me to another GUI when I press it, but I don't know how."*

I'm, not sure how the drag and drop works with GUI Builder for JPopupMenu. I tried to to drap and drop it, but it won't show the display, so I couldn't just drag and drop JMenuItems to it. So I had to hand code it.

- I dragged a JPopupMenu to the frame (`jPopupmenu1`);
- In the constructor, I added a `JMenuItem` to it.
- I added an `ActionListener` to the `JMenuItem`
- Just show instantiate the second GUI , and maybe dispose of the second, depending on your preference

---

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Open GUI2");
    jPopupMenu1.add(item1);
    item1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new GUI2();
        }
    });
}

....

private void formMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
            jPopupMenu1.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        }
    }                                 

private void formMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
            jPopupMenu1.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        }
    }
```

---

It works fine for me

[image]

Comment: There's little to nothing you can do to build a `JPopupMenu` with the GUI Builder, in my experience. But honestly, the GUI Builder should only be used for static components whose position doesn't need to change. Anytime you need "movable" components, imo, you need to hand-code.

Comment: @ryvantage I prefer hand coding myself. I just began learning GUI Builder, but there seems to be limitations. _And_ the code just doesn't look pretty at all.

Comment: I started with the Netbeans' GUI Builder and yes, there are a lot of limitations, but I rather enjoy them. I basically use the GUI Builder for positioning and nothing else (i.e., if I have a `JTable`, I just drag and drop it, position it, and create a separate method to load the data). Being able to visualize where my components are is crucial to me.